# get total of multiple columns using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having a problem on how to get the total of columns Amount1 - Amount5 each line.

I tried the below query but the result is always 0.

`Select ID, Amount1 + Amount2 + Amount3 + Amount4 as total_amount from table`

| ID | Amount1 | Amount2 | Amount3 | Amount4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 2 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 3 | 15 | 20 | 20 | 20 |

Hope you can help me on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Result can't be `0` for data you posted:

```
SQL> with test (id, amount1, amount2, amount3, amount4) as
  2    (select 1,  5,  5,  5,  5 from dual union all
  3     select 2, 10, 10, 10, 10 from dual union all
  4     select 3, 15, 20, 20, 20 from dual
  5    )
  6  select id,
  7         amount1 + amount2 + amount3 + amount4 as total_amount
  8  from test
  9  order by id;

        ID TOTAL_AMOUNT
---------- ------------
         1           20
         2           40
         3           75

SQL>
```

Therefore, either you did something wrong, or didn't post everything we should know to assist.

**Maybe** you use two connections to the same user; for one, you updated old values for all `amount` columns to what you posted, but the one that actually runs the `select` statement, they are still `0` because - in the first session - you didn't `COMMIT`.